# <generator object product at 0x000000000315C438>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error?? I dont know what it is and why its comming.

Here is my code:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
# product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
# product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
for prod in result:
    yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: 1. Your indentation is broken. 2. How do you call this function?

Comment: This is how I want to call the function and output it:

# product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy

Comment: [Read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). That's where you pulled the code from in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an error.  Instead, it is the object ID for the generator object created by `product`.

If you want the results as a list, put the function call in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list):

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
###############################
myproduct = list(product(...))
###############################
print (myproduct)
```

Below is a basic demonstration:

```
>>> def func():
...     for i in range(10):
...         yield i
...
>>> func()
<generator object func at 0x01ADA210>
>>> list(func())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: could u give example?

Comment: Please call it object ID instead of memory address. That is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @user3029969 - ? I thought I did.  You would do something like:  `myproduct = list(product('ABCD', 'xy'))`.

Comment: should I do that for both cases for pool in pools and prod in resuts?

Comment: I still cant comprehend how I can myproduct = list(product(...)) in the function?

Comment: @user3029969 - No, you want to do that where you _call_ the function.  The function should work fine.  You are modifying what is returned by it (namely, you are changing the generator object into a list.  See my edit.